# Migration User Data From Wordpress Table to Laravel MySQL User Table

Tags: mysql, laravel, wordpress, hash, md5

I am trying to migrate data from wordpress **WP_Users** table to Laravel MySQL Table. The problem is the **Password** field in WP_USERS use MD5 encryption whereas Laravel uses hash to store password. Is there a way/ tool to convert MD5 to Hash so that I can seamlessly migrate data from my old Wordpress app to New Laravel App? I am using **Laravel Breeze**

Answer (score 1):

No - You will need to change the login function to check the insecure md5, then as people log in, save it as an encrypted password in Laravel.

1. Add a field on the user table called `old_insecure_password` where you store the old WordPress password.
2. Change the login function first to check login using the Laravel encryption. If it fails, it should check if the password matches the `old_insecure_password` using the same md5 from WordPress. If it does, it should take that password and encrypt it into the `password` field, clear out the `old_insecure_password`, and continue to log in.

Or migrate it and force everyone to reset their password.

Feel free to edit your question as you get stuck on something concrete when trying out this process, and ping me here if you have any additional questions.